# Coldfusion PayPal IPN Connection Failure

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, connection, paypal-ipn, coldfusion-10

I am trying to get a sandbox PayPal IPN working with the Coldfusion example shown here:

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/coldfusion

I've added the location of my IPN file to PayPal and the page is being called by it but all I get is a 'Connection Failure' message in the text file. The IPN file is being called from an https location so not sure what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: First guess: maybe you need to add the certificate of `ipnpb.paypal.com` (and `ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com`) to coldfusion's keystore.

Comment: ok I can try that but how do I get the certificates for those sites?

Comment: Which version of "ColdFusion" are you using? PayPal is updating its services to require TLS 1.2  and CF9 doesn't support it. (I've been able to connect to TLS 1.2 on CF9 using CFX_HTTP5.)

Comment: it's Coldfusion 10, I think the problem may be TLS 1.2 support...or lack of...

Comment: Please review this QA for info on how to upgrade your JRE that supports TLS 1.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391119/how-to-add-tls-1-2-in-cfhttp-tag-in-coldfusion-10/47422390#47422390

Answer (score 0):

The JRE (version 7) that comes with ColdFusion 10, doesn't support TLS 1.2, which you require to talk to the PayPal API. You need to either update the JRE to 113+ and enable TLS 1.2 via argument or upgrade altogether to JRE 8. To upgrade, you have to let the `jvm.config` point to the installation and replace the `tools.jar` in CF with the one from the JDK 8. (Also make sure to have at least update 14 installed on your ColdFusion 10 server.)

Comment: the link from Scott above helped and everything seems to be working fine now.