# How to parse & read from .txt file (NOAA Weather)

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, noaa

I am trying to parse and read from a `.txt` file, from the NOAA Weather site.  How can I search the file to find certain text and insert it into the database?

I'm trying to search for Greenville and pull the conditions and temp. Then push that into my database, along with other cities?  Any code that you are willing to share would be appreciated.

*Code:*

```
<cffile action="read" file="#expandPath("./NWS Raleigh Durham.txt")#" variable="myFile">"
<cfdump var="#myfile#">
```

Content:

> National Weather Service Text Product Display Skip Navigation Regional Weather Roundup Issued by NWS Raleigh/Durham, NC Home | Current Version | Previous Version | Graphics & Text | Print | Product List | Glossary On Versions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 000 ASUS42 KRAH 081410 RWRRAH NORTH CAROLINA WEATHER ROUNDUP NATIONAL WEATHER SERVICE RALEIGH NC 900 AM EST THU MAR 08 2018 NOTE: "FAIR" INDICATES FEW OR NO CLOUDS BELOW 12,000 FEET WITH NO SIGNIFICANT WEATHER AND/OR OBSTRUCTIONS TO VISIBILITY. NCZ001-053-055-056-065-067-081500- WESTERN NORTH CAROLINA CITY SKY/WX TMP DP RH WIND PRES REMARKS ASHEVILLE FAIR 35 23 61 VRB3 29.92F JEFFERSON FLURRIES 26 16 65 W9 29.83F WCI 16 MORGANTON FAIR 37 25 64 NW3 29.97F HICKORY CLOUDY 35 24 64 SW5 29.94F WCI 31 RUTHERFORDTON CLOUDY 37 27 67 W6 29.97S WCI 33 MOUNT AIRY FAIR 37 21 53 NW8 29.94F WCI 31 BOONE PTSUNNY 27 16 63 NW13G18 29.85F WCI 16 $$ NCZ021-022-025-041-071-084-088-081500- CENTRAL NORTH CAROLINA CITY SKY/WX TMP DP RH WIND PRES REMARKS CHARLOTTE CLOUDY 38 27 64 W5 29.97F WCI 34 GREENSBORO PTSUNNY 38 24 57 W8 29.93S WCI 32 WINSTON-SALEM FAIR 38 20 48 W8 29.94F WCI 32 RALEIGH-DURHAM PTSUNNY 36 26 67 CALM 29.96R FORT BRAGG CLOUDY 39 23 52 NW5 29.97R FAYETTEVILLE CLOUDY 38 28 67 W6 29.98R WCI 33 BURLINGTON CLOUDY 39 25 57 SW5 29.94S LAURINBURG CLOUDY 38 28 67 NW8 29.99R WCI 32 $$ NCZ011-015-027-028-043-044-047-080-103-081500- NORTHEASTERN NORTH CAROLINA CITY SKY/WX TMP DP RH WIND PRES REMARKS ROCKY MT-WILSO PTSUNNY 40 24 53 NW6 29.96R GREENVILLE FAIR 41 23 48 N6 29.97S WASHINGTON FAIR 41 25 51 NW9 29.94F ELIZABETH CITY PTSUNNY 40 27 59 NW7 29.92S MANTEO CLOUDY 42 28 58 N9 29.91S CAPE HATTERAS FAIR 45 33 63 N5 29.90S $$ NCZ078-087-090-091-093-098-101-081500- SOUTHEASTERN NORTH CAROLINA CITY SKY/WX TMP DP RH WIND PRES REMARKS LUMBERTON CLOUDY 40 29 64 NW8 29.99R WCI 34 GOLDSBORO CLOUDY 39 25 57 NW5 29.94S KINSTON PTSUNNY 43 25 49 NW8 29.96S KENANSVILLE CLOUDY 39 27 60 NW7 29.96S WCI 34 NEW BERN FAIR 41 27 57 NW8 29.95S CHERRY POINT NOT AVBL BEAUFORT FAIR 45 28 51 NW13 29.93S JACKSONVILLE CLOUDY 43 27 53 NW9 29.95S WILMINGTON FAIR 44 27 51 NW13 29.96S $$ National Weather Service Raleigh, NC Weather Forecast Office 1005 Capability Drive, Suite 300 Centennial Campus Raleigh, NC 27606-5226 (919) 326-1042 Page Author: RAH Webmaster Web Master's E-mail: rah.webmaster@noaa.gov Page last modified: Jan 10th, 2018 19:57 UTC Disclaimer Credits Glossary Privacy Policy About Us Career Opportunities

Comment: If the file is delimited, read it with `cfhttp` instead of `cffile`.  The name attribute will create a query object which should be easier to work with.

Comment: Is there a reason your not using the [NOAA Web Services](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices)?

Comment: @DanBracuk What's your email address? Id like to email you directly about your post.  Orignally I was reading it with cfhttp, but when I dump cfhttp getting "Peer Not authenticated".  Could this be the issue why the data isn't being updated?  What's the fix for this? My email is sclayton@physicianseast.com

Comment: @WSC27 given "Peer Not authenticated" to an`cfhttp` my assumption in your now deleted question that it's a tls issue more weight. If I recall correctly, your on CF8, and it hasn't been supported in over 5 years. Your best course of action is to **update your server**. An alternate is to pass of the http calls to another application.

Comment: @Twillen I am using NOAA Web Services, but for some reason my weather data hasn't updated since last week. See post to DanBracuk above. I was using the text file parse as a work around, but hopefully parse txt method wont be needed.

Comment: I'm 99.9% possitive now that the "some reason" is due to [TLS 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is the only version supported with NOAA current certificate. CF 8 only supports TLS 1.0. [Related blog post](https://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2014/12/8/colfusion-jvm-versions-sslv3-tls). My suggestion is not to work around it, and just update your server.

Comment: You could also try James answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394301/923833), requires license of 3rd party software.

Comment: One of the reason's I won't give you my email is that this site is used for reference.  Others who have similar problems in the future should be able to see how your question got answered, or commented upon.

Comment: @WSC27 - Is there a reason you can't either a) upgrade or b) use the 3rd party tag CFX_HTTP5 like Twillen suggested? Screen scraping is very brittle ... It's simpler to just use the proper API.