# CFCase values with spaces are not found

Tags: coldfusion, html-parsing, case, coldfusion-8

As anyone had this issue with parsing from html file with setting `<cfcase>` values that contain spaces in the value?  If the value contains spaces ColdFusion isn't able to find the data match in the parsed html file.

For example:

```
<CFCASE value="LGT RAIN">
<CFSET application.condition="Lt Rain">
</CFCASE>`
```

The html file has the value "LGT RAIN", but due to the way its being parsed it is not defining the city's condition.  Is there a work around like check the condition prior to running your switch statements?  Like if "LGT RAIN" is found then set cfset value it to "LGTRAIN".

Here is sample [link](https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=CAE&issuedby=CAE&product=RWR&format=CI&version=1) that I am parsing from.

https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=CAE&issuedby=CAE&product=RWR&format=CI&version=1

```
<CFSET WeatherData = CFHTTP.FileContent>
```

*Code:*

```
<!--- Check For Condition with Two Word Phrase ---------------> 
<CFSET condition= #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 1, " ")#>
<br> 
<CFSET city = #attributes.citystring#> 
<CFIF (condition is "LGT") 
   or (condition is "HVY") 
   or (condition is "FRZ") 
   or (condition is "MIX") 
   or (condition is "NOT")> 
  <CFSET condition= ( 
    #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 1, " ")# 
    & " " & 
    #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 2, " ")#
  )>
  <br>
  <CFSET Temp = #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 3, " ")#>'
  .......
```

Comment: Are you sure that the character is a space? It seems to work fine here - https://trycf.com/gist/906f90ab7aeed217e583e6ea6469b9c0/acf?theme=monokai  Unless it truly is an issue with ColdFusion 8. If so, maybe you can use this as the final straw to upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: What code are you using to parse the weather file? I'm guessing that either (like Miguel said) that space in "LGT RAIN" isn't really a space character, or you have one leading or trailing your search text. Can you provide more sample code?

Comment: In addition to what @Miguel-F said, start by dumping each of the characters in "the value". See if they're really what you're expecting https://trycf.com/gist/9ce21260062e34a69503e172a42623f1/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: @Shawn Here is sample link that I am parasing from.  [link](https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=CAE&issuedby=CAE&product=RWR&format=CI&version=1) '<CFSET WeatherData = CFHTTP.FileContent>

Comment: @Shawn ' <!---   Check For Condition with Two Word Phrase ---------------> <CFSET condition= #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 1, " ")#><br> <CFSET city = #attributes.citystring#> <CFIF (condition is "LGT") or (condition is "HVY") or (condition is "FRZ") or (condition is "MIX") or (condition is "NOT")> <CFSET condition= ( #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 1, " ")# & " " & #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 2, " ")#)><br><CFSET Temp = #GetToken("#content#",#attributes.citystring# + 3, " ")#>'

Comment: @WSC27 add those details into the original question [edit], not as a comment. They are easier to read that way and can contain greater details. And from what I can tell, you are still not supplying an actual example of the data. We need to see what the content is as your code looks okay (at least the part that you included).

Comment: @Miguel-F To see the example of data url Click on the 'link' in above Shawn's post.

Comment: Isn't this coming from a space-delimited text file? You may be making a lot more work for yourself here. And also, should you be setting your condition in the `application` scope?

Comment: @Shawn Being parsed from html file. The condition is being set in the application scope.  Just didn't include that part of code.

Comment: @WSC27 yes I have seen the link that you posted earlier but that does not show us what your code "sees". We can't help you if you don't provide more details. As currently posted, there are no issues with the little bit of code you have shared. So we can only assume it is the data or your code that is parsing the data.

Comment: Also, that link has a text-only version that will give you a MUCH lighter payload to have to deal with. It strips out most of the excess HTML that you don't need anyway. That said, the text is still inside `<pre>` tags, so you'll have to provide us with some data about how you're parsing this page to get only what you want.

Comment: And my point about using the `application` scope wasn't so much that I couldn't see where it was but more a question of why using the `application` scope. If you have two requests coming in at the same time, that variable will leak.

Comment: @WSC27 - An important step in troubleshooting is learning how to create [short but complete programs](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/complete.html). When you run into an issue like this, start by creating a *standalone* example with the *smallest* amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. The process of doing so often helps you figure out the problem on your own. However, even if it doesn't, you now have a complete example that someone else can test on their own machine and .. the easier it is for someone else to test your code, the faster you'll get an answer.

Comment: ... and "complete" example often means hard coding variable values. For example, `<cfset attributes.citystring = 123>`.  Otherwise we won't be able to reproduce the results you're seeing, which makes it very difficult to help.

Comment: Also, I believe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of missing context on what you're trying to ultimately do with the weather you get, so I made a couple of assumptions on ways to parse through the weather block.

You'll have to actually parse the page to get that actual block, but once you do, you can use my suggestions below to split those weather elements out. I got rid of the `getToken()` calls, because I think that may have been more work than you needed, and was essentially led to the problem with spaces. My code is still much wordier than I intended, but I tried to make sure I wasn't using anything above CF8. I *think* it should all work, but I don't have a CF8 server to test on.

https://trycf.com/gist/1993243eb476a629ec25f8c6e8ddff3c/acf?theme=monokai

I've included some notes inside the code as I went along.

```
<!--- Create a block of the parsed weather. --->
<cfsavecontent variable="myWX">ANDERSON       FAIR      49  16  26 W12G20    30.01F
LIBERTY        FAIR      49  14  24 W12G21    29.99F
SPARTANBURG    FAIR      45   9  23 NW12G21   30.00F
CLEMSON        FAIR      48  10  21 NW13G22   30.02F
GREENVILLE     FAIR      48  13  24 VRB3      29.99F
GREENWOOD      FAIR      49  13  23 W10G21    30.03F
GREER          FAIR      48   9  20 VRB7      29.99F
ROCK HILL      FAIR      46  17  31 NW10G22   29.99F
CHESTER        FAIR      45  12  26 W12G17    30.01F
LAURENS        FAIR      48  16  27 NW12G18   30.01F
</cfsavecontent>

 <!--- end of line character (this may change if your feed uses other eol)--->
<cfset crlf = chr(13)&chr(10)>

<!--- Make weather an array of strings for each city. --->
<cfset wxArray = ListToArray(myWX, crlf, false, true)>
```

My suggestion is to put the different elements in a struct, then work with that. 1 row of city weather = 1 row of Struct.

My code below assumes you are parsing rows of a 65 character fixed-width record from the HTML, which is what it appears to be when you get at the individual rows.

```
<!--- Loop through the new weather array and make a new array of parsed weather. --->
<!--- Create initial weather array for output. --->
<cfset newWXArray = []> 
<cfloop array="#wxArray#" index="wxRow">
    <!--- NOTE: Yay go CF8s implicit struct creation! --->
    <cfset WXRow = {
        city = trim(mid(wxRow,1,15)) , <!--- trim() will remove leading/trailing spaces --->
        sky  = trim(mid(wxRow,16,10)) ,
        tmp  = trim(mid(wxRow,26,4)) ,
        dp   = trim(mid(wxRow,30,4)) ,
        rh   = trim(mid(wxRow,34,3)) ,
        wind = trim(mid(wxRow,37,10)) ,
        pres = trim(mid(wxRow,47,6)) , 
        rmks = trim(mid(wxRow,53,11))
    }>
    <!--- ArrayAppend() returns true/false, so this variable isn't used. --->
    <cfset throwaway = ArrayAppend(newWXArray, WXRow)>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#newWXArray#">
```

Now you have an array of all the cities, and can pull the individual pieces out for the city you need.

```
What's the weather like in Liberty? <br>

<cfset whichRow = 0> 
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(newWXArray)#" index="i"> 
    <cfif newWXArray[i].CITY IS "LIBERTY"> 
        <cfset whichRow = i> 
    </cfif> 
</cfloop> 

<cfoutput>
City >> #newWXArray[whichRow].CITY# <br>
Sky >> #newWXArray[whichRow].SKY# <br>
Temp >> #newWXArray[whichRow].TMP# <br>
DewPoint >> #newWXArray[whichRow].DP# <br>
Relative Humidity >> #newWXArray[whichRow].RH# <br>
Wind >> #newWXArray[whichRow].WIND# <br>
Pressure >> #newWXArray[whichRow].PRES# <br>
Remarks >> #newWXArray[whichRow].RMKS# <br>
</cfoutput>
```

**Final Note:**

I had forgotten how limited CF8 was. There is a lot of stuff you can do to make this *MUCH* easier if you are able to upgrade to a current version of ACF or Lucee.

Also, as I suggested, changing your link to pull the Text-Only version (https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=CAE&issuedby=CAE&product=RWR&format=txt&version=1&glossary=1) will significantly reduce the amount of text you have to parse through.

Comment: WSC27 - Yes, do upgrade if at all possible since the [original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194488/how-to-parse-read-from-txt-file-noaa-weather) causing problems with the official api is probably related to the outdated jvm used by CF8. @Shawn - Didn't even remember CF8 supported implicit arrays/structures! Couldn't find the original docs, but [this blog](https://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/07/listtoarray-in-coldfusion-8.html) says CF8's ListToArray doesn't support the `multicharacterdelim` param.

Comment: Doh! Again, I'd forgotten how many headaches from CF8 led to some of the things that are now easily taken for granted. I've looked at some of my early code I wrote in the CF4.0 days and thought 
Now why did I do that?...... Oh yeah."

Answer (score 1):

My experience with white space in text data messing up conditional logic has been with trailing spaces but the principles are the same.  When in doubt look at your data.  Here is a simple example:

```
MyVar = 'Lgt  Rain';  // two spaces between the words
if (MyVar == 'Lgt Rain'){ // one space between words
applicable code
}
else {
writeoutput(replace(MyVar, ' ', '-space-', 'all'));
}
```