# Updating ColdFusion 9 For TLS 1.2 Usage

Tags: java-8, coldfusion, tls1.2, coldfusion-9

We are using ColdFusion 9.0.1 with jdk 1.7.0_75 version. We have to use TLS 1.2 in our systems.

We have tried:

- Adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` line to JRun4 > bin > jmv.config file.
- Installed jdk1.8.0_172 - jdk1.8.0_221 versions and changed JRun4 > bin > jmv.config > `java.home` path. After that when I open a web page, it opens an empty page. It is empty between body tags. There is no error.

  I have read this article [Server and JRE are set to TLS 1.2 but Coldfusion 9 still trying to use TLS 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767125/server-and-jre-are-set-to-tls-1-2-but-coldfusion-9-still-trying-to-use-tls-1-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) . I can use ColdFusion 9 with Java 8 without problem.

How can I use ColdFusion 9 with TLS 1.2?

My OS Windows 2008 Server R2, running on Vmware and JRE 8 installed already.

Thanks for you replies.

Comment: Have you checked out CFX_HTTP5? (This is what we used w/CF8 + 9 when connecting to TLS1.2 hosts or dealing with hosts configured with dynamic/round-robin DNS.)

Comment: You should also replace the `tools.jar` with the JDK one of Java 8. CF uses it for some of its features.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767125/server-and-jre-are-set-to-tls-1-2-but-coldfusion-9-still-trying-to-use-tls-1-0/50778381#50778381

Answer (score 0):

You say you get a white page and see no errors. Where did you look for errors? I tried something with CF9 recently and used CommandBox. An exception was thrown during startup of the ColdFusion instance, when I used a recent JAVA 8. I was told CF9 does not work with JAVA after 1.8.92 - because of some security related changes made in later versions. Exception contained: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: FIPS186PRNG, provider: JsafeJCE, class: com.rsa.jsafe.provider.JSA_FIPS186PRNGXChangeNoticeGeneral)`

Try to get the old JAVA 1.8.92 Server JRE (simply unzip in a folder of your choice) from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Comment: The CF9 server that I support is running on top of Server JRE 1.8u172.

Comment: I tried it with JDK 1.8.172 and got some errors :( https://gist.github.com/bardware/99be3f027e69282ebfc359ed9535b92f

Comment: Looks like you are using CF 9.01 on CommandBox.  I'm using CF 9.01 as a stand-alone server on IIS.  I'll try it out on CommandBox when I get some time and let you know what I find out.  I recently downloaded 1.8u221 so I may try updating to that version first.